# Transform of UIImageView.layer affects UIScrollView zoomScale

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, transform, calayer

I have a UIImageView that is in a UIScrollView.  I load images into the UIImageView's CALayer with the following code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: fileToDisplay];    
NSLog(@"If I don't flip image imageScrollView.zoomScale: %f", imageScrollView.zoomScale);
[[imageView layer] setContents: (id)image.CGImage];
if (flipped)
{
    [[imageView layer] setTransform: CATransform3DMakeRotation(180.0 / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)];
    NSLog(@"If image flipped imageScrollView.zoomScale: %f", imageScrollView.zoomScale);
}
```

I am 'flipping' the image about the y axis.  The unexpected event is that the transformation of the imageView.layer is changing the imageScrollView.zoomScale as shown in the following output:

If I don't flip image imageScrollView.zoomScale: 0.465455

If image flipped imageScrollView.zoomScale: 1.000000

My question is how do I make this not happen?  If there is no way to do defeat this behavior, what do I have to do to achieve the image framing that is performed on images I do not flip.  In other words just setting the zoomScale to what it was prior to the transform does not work.  Something else has changed in the UIScrollView (not the contentSize or the contentOffset).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using a `CATransform3DMake...` method, you're creating a new transform and replacing the current transform. You need to use `CATransform3DRotate` instead, to add the rotation to the current transform (which is used for the scale).

```
imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(imageView.layer.transform , 180.0 / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```